# Crontab: running app with flags

Tags: cron, flags

I would like to know how can I run an application with crontab if the app uses flags:

```
30   0   *   *   *   root   myapp --run
```

I have searched similar questions here but I haven't found any approximate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to use as much params as you want, everything after 'schedule expression' treated as your execution command 

`30 0 * * * /sbin/ping -c 1 192.168.0.1 > /dev/null`